# Mysql crash when querying

Tags: mysql, sql, select, crash

When I select with 2 conditions, mysql is always crashed.For me the problem is very strange:

1. It's just for this table
2. It's only happened on my notebook. We have test server (linux) with the same version mysql and the same sql is ok
3. It's not happened with either condition only
4. I tried drop and recreate the table, dump data and problem is still
5. I tried reinstall the same version mysql and in my notebook it happened again
6. Someone said mysql 5.6 is Ok, I haven't try

Mysql version is 5.7.17.OS: win7 64. I want to use 5.7. Can anybody give some advice.

PS: Is is possible that the problem is relevant with `my.cnf`?

Error log:

```html
01:15:19 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc000001d ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68005 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0xe5fe040
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
13ff93c21    mysqld.exe!pow()[pow.asm:1616]
13f4d3b4b    mysqld.exe!get_sweep_read_cost()[handler.cc:7055]
13fa90117    mysqld.exe!ror_intersect_add()[opt_range.cc:5430]
13fa861e9    mysqld.exe!get_best_ror_intersect()[opt_range.cc:5611]
13fa923b5    mysqld.exe!test_quick_select()[opt_range.cc:3078]
13f68bdde    mysqld.exe!get_quick_record_count()[sql_optimizer.cc:5890]
13f68a8cd    mysqld.exe!JOIN::estimate_rowcount()[sql_optimizer.cc:5636]
13f68d479    mysqld.exe!JOIN::make_join_plan()[sql_optimizer.cc:4993]
13f68ef3f    mysqld.exe!JOIN::optimize()[sql_optimizer.cc:363]
13f66a659    mysqld.exe!st_select_lex::optimize()[sql_select.cc:1009]
13f66852d    mysqld.exe!handle_query()[sql_select.cc:164]
13f5227f6    mysqld.exe!execute_sqlcom_select()[sql_parse.cc:4947]
13f5246de    mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:2597]
13f527faa    mysqld.exe!mysql_parse()[sql_parse.cc:5363]
13f5212c9    mysqld.exe!dispatch_command()[sql_parse.cc:1287]
13f52226a    mysqld.exe!do_command()[sql_parse.cc:854]
13f4c9634    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:295]
13fedad82    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2195]
13fc046fb    mysqld.exe!win_thread_start()[my_thread.c:38]
13ff9b39f    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstartex()[threadex.c:376]
13ff9b5ea    mysqld.exe!_threadstartex()[threadex.c:354]
773af56d    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
77723281    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (e61cf50): select * from sys_dauth_filter_item
where ENTITY_ID_ = 1
and FIELD_ID_ = 1
Connection ID (thread ID): 2
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Comment: Was about to down vote and  comment that mysql doesn't crash when querying but I see that it has crashed!!

Comment: That's strange! Have a try with `select column1,column2` instead of `select *`? Also try with left/right join instead of full join.

Comment: I have tried select count, select *, select column1, column2....All have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to update the Windows.

In my case, MySql 5.7.17, Windows 2008 R2 server, update Win to sp1 => solve that problem.

Reference: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81197

My error log:

```
Thread pointer: 0x5705b3850
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
140692571    mysqld.exe!pow()[pow.asm:1616]
13fc439a8    mysqld.exe!Item_func_pow::val_real()[item_func.cc:2924]
13fc03188    mysqld.exe!Item::send()[item.cc:7566]
13fc167a2    mysqld.exe!THD::send_result_set_row()[sql_class.cc:4661]
13fc15a1c    mysqld.exe!Query_result_send::send_data()[sql_class.cc:2716]
140158d8f    mysqld.exe!JOIN::exec()[sql_executor.cc:158]
13fd6d1e1    mysqld.exe!handle_query()[sql_select.cc:185]
13fbe4107    mysqld.exe!execute_sqlcom_select()[sql_parse.cc:5195]
13fbe6036    mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:2794]
13fbe9a83    mysqld.exe!mysql_parse()[sql_parse.cc:5617]
13fbe2b83    mysqld.exe!dispatch_command()[sql_parse.cc:1464]
13fbe3b7a    mysqld.exe!do_command()[sql_parse.cc:1001]
13fbb981c    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:300]
1405d7392    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2191]
1402efc4b    mysqld.exe!win_thread_start()[my_thread.c:38]
140699a3f    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstartex()[threadex.c:376]
140699c8a    mysqld.exe!_threadstartex()[threadex.c:354]
770cf34d    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
77302ca1    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (57133e640): SELECT POWER(1024,1)
Connection ID (thread ID): 5
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: Sorry, everyone! I made a mistake.My OS is WIN 7. At first I thought it was   Win 10. And updating the OS really solved the problem.